# measure kafka performance metrics(transactions per second,memory)

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using connecter Golden gate(producer) to kafka to stream messages.All configurations/machines resides on AWS Ec2 and would like to measure the performance(tps,memory,cpu). we have linux machines which we can use for performance evaluation. Could anyone suggest how to get the TPS,memory usage in linux? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Kafka ships with performance testing tools in the ./bin sub directory such as bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh and bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test